# Get Record from two table using codeigniter where all matching record from first table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables:

1. Student [id, studname, school, bid, ...]
2. attendance [id, sid, bid, attenDate, ...]

sid: student id
bid: batch id

I am trying to get record from `Student` table of on batch and `attendance` of same batch of one particular date.

But I am getting record/list of `student` whose `id` are avail in `attendance`.

Student Table:

[image: Student Table]

Attendance Table:

[image: Attendance Table]

In both cases, I'm getting only two records. I am expecting 3 student list.

```
SELECT * FROM students s LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance a ON s.id = a.sid WHERE s.bid=1 AND a.attenDate='2017-03-18'

$condition = ['s.bid'=>$bid,'a.attenDate'=>$adate];         
$listattend = $this->db->select('*')
                       ->from('students s')
                       ->join('attendance a', 's.id = a.sid', 'right outer')
                       ->where($condition)
                       ->get();                                 
return $listattend->result();
```

Comment: add table structur & data in question

Comment: @Rafiq I added table images in question along with data

Comment: But it requires time to get table & data from image. So it will be better if you add table structure and data in question or in [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to solve problem early. Thanks

Comment: what is the data type of attenDate column ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.*,s* FROM attendance a LEFT JOIN students s ON a.sid = s.id AND a.bid=s.bid WHERE DATE(a.date) = "2017-02-05"
```

Comment: Nop. Its not working it give all record of all dates. Actually here problem is that date. Which i am unable to solve. I am unable combine the currently. "WHERE   s.bid=1 AND a.attenDate='2017-03-18'" this one